# How to search including “>” or “<“ in search bar using searchable?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create searchable variable  so when I enter > and amount in the search bar then I get a list of all transaction equal or greater than amount entered or

when I enter < and amount in the search bar then I get a list of all transaction equal or less than amount entered.

For example when I enter >50 in the search bar I want to filter list of all transaction equal or greater that 50

Following is the code example for the reference:

```
struct Items: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String
    let amount: Double
    static var samples: [Items] = [
        Items(name: "item 1", amount: 10.9),
        Items(name: "item 2", amount: 50.0),
        Items(name: "item 3", amount: 30.7),
        Items(name: "item 4", amount: -10.9),
        Items(name: "item 5", amount: 80.3),
        Items(name: "item 6", amount: 15.3),
        Items(name: "item 7", amount: 80.0),
    ]
}
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var queryList: [Items] = Items.samples
    @State var searchQuery = ""
    
    var searchResult: [Items] {
        guard !searchQuery.isEmpty else {return queryList}
        return
            queryList.filter({$0.amount >= (Double(searchQuery) ?? 0) || $0.amount <= Double(searchQuery) ?? 0})

    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            
            List {
                ForEach(searchResult) { list in
                    HStack {
                        Text(list.name)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(list.amount)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .searchable(text: $searchQuery)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this approach, using a modified `searchResult`, such as:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String
    let amount: Double
    
    static var samples: [Item] = [
        Item(name: "item 1", amount: 10.9),
        Item(name: "item 2", amount: 50.0),
        Item(name: "item 3", amount: 30.7),
        Item(name: "item 4", amount: -10.9),
        Item(name: "item 5", amount: 80.3),
        Item(name: "item 6", amount: 15.3),
        Item(name: "item 7", amount: 80.0)
    ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var queryList: [Item] = Item.samples
    @State var searchQuery = ""
    
   var searchResult: [Item] {
    // remove any blank spaces
    let search = searchQuery.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    guard !search.isEmpty else {return queryList}

    // extract the operator
    let op = String(search.prefix(1))
    // remove the operator, to get just the value part
    let value = String(search.dropFirst())
    let doubleVal = Double(value) ?? 0.0

    // operator conditions
    if op == ">" {
        return queryList.filter({$0.amount >= doubleVal})
    }
    if op == "<" {
        return queryList.filter({$0.amount <= doubleVal})
    }
    // up to you here
    return queryList.filter({$0.amount == Double(search) ?? 0.0})
}
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(searchResult) { list in
                    HStack {
                        Text(list.name)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(list.amount)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .searchable(text: $searchQuery)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```